# How to loose weight as a 17 year old?

Tags: diet, mental-health, weight-loss

I'm a 17 year old male teenager. Currently my weight is around 95 kg and my height is 175 cm.
This year I need to focus most on my studies and because of this I don't get time to exercise. Also exercising makes me very tired because of which much of my precious time is wasted. I follow a strict vegetarian diet (including dairy products). Sometimes when I have some spare time I do some push-ups and do a little bit of exercise in my room and I'm comfortable doing that. I currently aim to get my weight around 75 kgs. I do walk around 10k steps daily.
So if anyone has some spare time and any suggestion or tip to tell me  they are very much welcomed.
THANK YOU.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Recommending a personal weight reduction plan falls under personal medical advice, which is strictly off-topic here, since health is an important topic and such advice has to be given by a physician who has a chance to examine you and who has an insight into your overall health. For more information please see the [help] or take our [tour]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly found your question and I couldn't help but type an answer even though I am no expert (but I have dealt with that issue at times, actually at your age). I do not know what the deal is with this deserted stack exchange, but I will try my best because I found it worrying what you wrote.

You do not have time for some moderate Cardio 30 minutes three times a week? Cardio, not some walking. Forget trackers for the amount of steps, they do not work. You have to do your sport in your room? How is it a waste of time if you want to lose weight? How does one even study with that intensity? Here is my advice: Track every calorie you eat and try to end up with a deficit of 300-500 every single day. There are a couple of apps that can help or you can do it the old school way with pen and paper. You will not lose weight unless you are at a deficit.

I really wonder what you have to study so hard for. I ended up with almost perfect grades at your age and still had the time to lose more than 30 kg with sport, but I also grew up in a Western country where school is really easy. Push ups burn almost no calories, be aware of that. Just walking does a little bit, but it is all too easy to just eat what you have burned in a couple of hours. You will even see that in the long run, instead of making you tired that sport will help you study. Your life has just begun, in 20 years you will run into some serious problems if you do not run enough now.

Also, do not expect fast results. First you lose water and so on and not fat and then your weight will no longer change for a while. This will take some time - we are talking about almost a year here.

So long story short: Track everything (except your steps). This isn't rocket science. If you are a hard studier, you should have no problem with doing some simple calculations.

Comment: Overall decent answer. However, you need to add some references in order to keep this answer from being downvoted and deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Health! To add to @L.B.s valid point: Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: It's kind of hard for me to concentrate while studying so that's why I have to give much more time than it is actually needed. Anyways thank you for your suggestions!